# Reuse the description of an existing Error when creating a new Error

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have the following code in Rust, which does not compile, but shows the intent of what I'd like to do.

```
    pub fn parse(cursor: &mut io::Cursor<&[u8]>) -> io::Result<Ack> {
        use self::byteorder::{BigEndian, ReadBytesExt};
        use self::core::error::Error;

        match cursor.read_u16::<BigEndian>() {
            Err(byteorder::Error::Io(error)) => Err(error),
            Err(error) =>
                Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, error.description(),
                                   None)),
            Ok(value) => Ok(Ack { block_number: value })
        }
    }
```

Essentially, I want to take the error description of an error returned by the byteorder library and use it to create the description of an error I'll pass back to the user of my library. This fails with `packets.rs:166:58: 166:63 error:`error`does not live long enough`, and I understand why.

The byteorder library solves this issue by wrapping an `std::io::Result` in the `byteorder::Error::Io` constructor. However, I don't want to take this route because I'd have to define my own error type that wraps either an `std::io::Error` or a `byteorder::Error`. It seems to me that my users shouldn't know or care that I use the byteorder library, and it shouldn't be part of my interface.

I'm a Rust newbie and don't yet know the idioms and best practices of the language and design. What are my options for dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in fact in that [`io::Error::new()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.new)'s second parameter is `&'static str`, while [`byteorder::Error::description()`](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/byteorder/enum.Error.html#method.description) returns a `&'a str` where `'a` is lifetime of the error object itself which is less than `'static`. Hence you can't use it for `io::Error`'s description.

The simplest fix would be moving `byteorder::Error` description to `detail` field of `io::Error`:

```
Err(error) =>
    Err(io::Error::new(
        io::ErrorKind::Other,
        "byteorder error",
        Some(error.description().to_string())
    )),
```

However, you should seriously consider making a custom wrapper error type which encapsulates all "downstream" errors. With properly written [`FromError`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.FromError.html) instances you should be able to write something like

```
try!(cursor.read_u16::<BigEndian>()
    .map(|value| Ack { block_number: value }))
```

instead of your whole match. Custom error wrappers will also help you when your program grows and more "downstream" error sources appear - you could just add new enum variants and/or `FromError` implementations to support these new errors.

Comment: I ended up implementing the custom error wrapper, as it seems like the most idiomatic way of doing this. I haven't tried it yet, but the try!...map approach is neat.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test your code so I can't be sure. Isn't the ref keyword enough?

```
Err(byteorder::Error::Io(ref error)) => Err(error),
```

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to get back to this again until tomorrow, but I'll try it out and report back. Thanks.